# LWC: Is it safe to rely on window.location.href to get the page url?

Tags: lightning-web-components, url

Is the SF team planning on deprecating support for the window object?

If so is there a lwc way to get the current url for the loaded page of the component? I couldn't find anything going through the current documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check [Secure Wrappers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_global_access) and [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) to get good idea - but it seems to have access and no documentation which says the access would be revoked.

However, the recommended way of getting page reference is through using [NavigationMixin & CurrentPageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url).

Sample code JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin, CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Poc extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getpageRef(pageRef) {
        console.log('data => ', JSON.stringify(pageRef));
    }
}
```

Output:

When above component was used in Aura component (Name:`POC_AURA`) which was loaded directly (isUrlAddressable interface), we get below object as logged:

```
{
  "type": "standard__component",
  "attributes": {
    "componentName": "c__POC_AURA"
  },
  "state": {
    "c__id": "some_id"
  }
}
```

When the same LWC component is put in record page of account, we get below logged:

```
{
  "type": "standard__recordPage",
  "attributes": {
    "objectApiName": "Account",
    "recordId": "0010K000028HCgAQAW",
    "actionName": "view"
  },
  "state": {

  }
}
```

You can refer to different [pageReference types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) that you get.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer as it has salesforce recommended ways of getting the url.

Comment: Dude, you are the man! Thanks so much!

Comment: yes this is especially correct when accessing current url in public site or community

Answer (score 4):

The best I can find is that when you use `window`, locker service returns a [`secureWindow`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_global_access.htm) object with some differences. You can find the differences [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) but it doesn't go into detail what those differences are.

You can test functionality in the [locker console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this link, that's awesome! Never seen that before. I'm definitely bookmarking this.